# How to cut a single pdf page in parts and save each part as images

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

I have a pdf with 10 question in it and now I want to create  separate images of fix size for each question saved in a separate folder. How to do it automatically

Comment: I doubt there is a way to do this automatically, but I may be wrong.  I think you're going to have to do it manually.  At least there are only 10 questions ;)

Comment: it is possible to script photoshop or to record actions for later. These solutions are difficult to implement and not worth it unless it the most extreme case because the documentation is so scattered.

Comment: This is a "Thesis!" ;)  .. in my mid there is 3 options to do that automatically .. I promise if there is time I will post a complete "how to do: answer with the 3 solutions. for now -briefly- there is 3 solution to do that ... 1-by using printing poster in print dialogue box. 2-using Evermap auto-split ... a plugin in Acrobat doing what you are asking for. 3-using an action with batch in Acrobat by cropping a saving the splitted PDF into a new one.

Comment: If you found that any of the answers below answered your question, please tick the "accepted"-marker next to that. Good for you, and good for the community.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do. Just not necessarily worth it for 10 things which you can manually split off in a minute or so. The question is generically valid tough. You *might* after all have 10,000 questions, images etc, that need to be split up.

The biggest question for the computer is how does it know what the things are. What is the recurring trend that says question changed? After all each question can be different lengths, images might have different sizes.

So there must be some recurring pattern that the computer can base its instructions on.

Is the data just text? If so you can export it as RTF and cut that up. RTF is beautiful when you want just the text or just bitmap images. Or you could search and replace to find the bounding box for the text then spit that up. And so on there's no one strategy that attacks all problems. Acrobat comes with a javascript api that can crop pages.

That said for 10 questions I would just draw artboards around questions in illustrator and save all artboards out separately. Or use indesign

Answer (score 0):

Here are my directions for you

1. Import the PDF File to Photoshop as Image.
2. Apply background as white because most of the time pdf is imported with transparent background
3. Then by using slice tool slice down your areas of questions.
4. After slicing, choose File->Save for Web
5. Select the format you need from the dialog appeared
6. Then click Save and Choose filename and folder.

I hope it'll be useful for you.